# Linux analog to Apple’s os.activity

Tags: swift, linux, linux-kernel

I’m working on a large Swift library, porting it from macOS to Linux. The only piece I have left is a critical component that employs Apple’s `os.activity` library. It’s unfortunate the original authors chose that approach, but here we are.

The software uses `os.activity` to obtain unique task (thread?) identifiers and use them as keys into a table maintaining “contexts” bound to each task. The Apple library supports this so that the identifiers don’t need to be passed around to other code areas. Very nice, but it was written to support os.log, not for the way it’s used in the library I’m porting.

Does anyone know of a Linux analog to `os.activity`? I’m presently looking at the user context API, as well as pthreads. The rub here is that Swift’s support for `await()` calls - asynchronous behavior - allows “tasks” to cross thread boundaries. Thus, just using a thread ID is apparently insufficient.

NB: I’m doing research currently on the Linux user context API in libc, but am not yet sure this will be sufficient.

Comment: Hmm. I might be able to use Swift’s Task Local support. Interesting…

Comment: Yup, it just might be that Swift task locals weren’t available when this library was written. Still soliciting advice, though.

Comment: `os_activity_t` is more than just a thread identifier. It represents a high-level, human-named activity of your code, and helps you track related computation across GCD dispatches. I'm not sure how it interacts with other concurrency constructs (e.g. I would expect it probably get inherited by child `Task`s in Swift concurrency, not new primitive `Thread`s being spawned). You could definitely try to simulate something _similar_ with Task-local values and their inheritance.

Comment: The APIs are a bit rough (written for C without much Swift lacquer to make them nicer), but the concept is actually really useful. I wouldn't say it's "unfortunate" that the original authors used it. To the contrary, it's a much underutilized developer tool, so I'd say it's a good thing they even used it (even if it's not portable). You can either find an equivalent in Linux, or perhaps you don't need it at all. It's just used to improve debugging in Instruments and logging in Console. If you're going to do your dev work only on macOS, you can just write a wrapper that no-ops on Linux.

Comment: @Alexander: I only wrote “unfortunate”, as one of goals of this library is portability. I agree that os.activity is very cool. I’m currently researching Swift’s task local API to see if that’s a suitable alternative on Linux. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander Wait. Do you mean os.activity is simply a debugging tool? This library I’m porting employs activity identifiers as keys into maps of contexts (a library concept). Seems like the authors rely on this for deployed functionality. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I've only ever seen it used as a developer tool. It's used to tag extra information in instruments traces (in the "Points of Interest" instrument, IIRC) and Console (each log message can have an "Activity ID"). It lets you define a set of activities and the connections between them (e.g. a parent activity "open file" might have children "load from disk", "parse file", "prepare caches", etc.), so you can get better attribution of what "high level activity" a "low level activity" was done for.. I've never seen it be used for the app's own functionality, that's... weird.

Comment: You _can_ probably mimic this with task-locals and some other tools, but it would probably be pretty hard to get an exact match with how `os.activity`'s are propagated. If you can't get it exactly to match, I would caution against doing it at all. The mismatches would just be false and frustrating in debugging. How exactly does your app use these, if not just for development/debugging?

Comment: @Alexander. How interesting! So the library I’m porting is OpenTelemetry-swift. It was originally written for MacOS, iOS, tvOS, et al.  Now Linux support is necessary, and I’m doing the work because we need it here at PassiveLogic. The library is using os.telemetry identifiers as keys into a map of OTEL contexts.

Comment: @Alexander You raise an interesting point. Why did the authors use os.activity to begin with? Did they want Swift task locals but that feature was unavailable at the time? I’ve conversed with several contributors and have only received an explanation of how activity identifiers are used; not why. And I already understood usage. Interesting!

Comment: I’m guessing I don’t need an exact match to activity’s behavior. But it’s very interesting to know that logging/debugging is the intended activity target.

Comment: For its intended use as a development tool, that if you're going to try to replicate it on Linux, I think it's _very_ important that it matches the behaviour on macOS _very_ well. If it doesn't, I'd argue its better to not have it at all. The risk is that if you have devs working on this who use a mix of Linux and macOS, any discrepancies between the two platforms would be very surprising/mysterious/counter-productive, and could be a total breakdown in communication. For its use in the production behaviour of the library itself, well... I'd need to know more about that

Comment: @Alexander All good points. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, hope it helps. Just to clarify, when I say “not have it at all,” I mean the Linux variant. I would wrap the os.activity API calls in a wrapper that does the real deal on macOS, and no-ops on Linux.

Comment: @Alexander Agreed. And thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge. Cheers!